# Seaweedfs merge/write received buffer data to file

Tags: audio, stream, seaweedfs

I would like to ask question about Seaweedfs functionality.

In my case, I have a browser where is audio recorder.
Audio chunk files are transferred to NodeJS backend using socket.
When chunk is at backend I have to save it in storage and merge together.
Does Seaweedfs supports functionality where buffer data is received and merged in storage?

Or maybe there is a better solution how I can store audio chunks in live recording and merge them together getting full audio file at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I added a filer REST API to append to a file. You can wait for the weekly release next Sunday.

Does that work for you?

```
    //create or append the file
    POST /path/to/file?op=append
    PUT /path/to/file?op=append
```

Comment: So basically sounds correct, if that API endpoint know how to append to file.
My tmp solution now in my nodeJS app is something like this using FS lib 

`appendTempFile (fileName, data) {
    return fs.appendFile(/tmp/${fileName}, data)
}
`

Comment: Is it possible to release these changes on this Sunday ? :)

Comment: Here has the up-to-minute builds https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs/releases/tag/dev

Comment: Tested your latest commits in master.  
Its not appending two webm audio files. Looks like it's rewrites first file

Comment: I uploaded two test audio files what i used for testing - copy this link in browser `we.tl/t-DNeYRT2gyv`


curl -F file=@first_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio/"
{"name":"first_part.webm","size":39347}
curl -F file=@second_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio/first_part.webm?op=append"
{"name":"second_part.webm","size":39636}

Comment: second test 

curl -F file=@first_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio3/first_part.webm?op=append"
{"name":"first_part.webm","size":39347}

 curl -F file=@second_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio3/first_part.webm?op=append"
{"name":"second_part.webm","size":39636}

third test 

curl -X POST -F file=@first_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio4/first_part.webm?op=append"
{"name":"first_part.webm","size":39347}

curl -X PUT -F file=@second_part.webm "http://localhost:8888/audio4/first_part.webm?op=append"
{"size":39844}

Comment: it is not reporting the total size, just the uploaded size. did you check the file itself?

Comment: I added a fix so that it will show the new total file size.

Comment: Ok, i will try to test it